# Use Cases of UIImagePickerController and ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary

I'm just wondering that, In which cases we should use `UIImagePickerController` and `ALAssetsLibrary`.

I gone through  [ALAssetsLibrary class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722) and [UIImagePickerController class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) and 
I found that

1. `UIImagePickerController` can capture image/video on the fly as well and `ALAssetsLibrary` can only list media and photo.
2. `ALAssetsLibrary` can list photos coming from iTunes, and those that were directly imported into the device.
3. With the help of `UIImagePickerController` you can choose media **as well**.

But still I'm not clear about the **use cases** of these two classes. I mean if I can list photos/media and choose those by using `UIImagePickerController`, than what's the real use of `ALAssetsLibrary`. **Any Ideas?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't really too comparable because they're for two completely different things.

UIImagePickerController should be used when you want to provide a system styled UI for your user to quickly take or select a photo or video for use within your app. That's basically all it does.

The Assets Library framework is meant to give you more control over the photo library. With this framework, you can enumerate all the photos in the library or individual albums, which is useful if you want to create your own custom interface for displaying the users photos. It also allows you to create albums, and save images and videos back into these albums.

Note: The Assets Library framework has no ability to access the camera. If you want manual control over this, use AVFoundation.

Comment: you mean to say, if I want to display some custom view to choose/pick media or still photo, one should use this and by using this Framework my app will be able to create new albums and store media and photo to newly created album.

Comment: @SuryakantSharma Correct. Basically, the difference is in what amount of control you have over the process. For example, if you used the assets library, you could technically create your own photo chooser UI that (for example) only allowed the user to select landscape photos.

Comment: Nice!!!
Can I access albums/photos create by my app using  Assets Library framework in photo app.

Comment: @SuryakantSharma Yes you can.